# git - Change all global settings

Tags: git, msysgit

I have two repos that I want to have different info associated with it.

For example one repo is named `site` and I want

```
user.name = admin
user.email =  admin@mysite.com
```

and for the all other repos I want

```
user.name = qwertymk
user.email = qwertymk@blah.com
```

Is there any way to switch profiles or something similar in git?

I'm on windows so I'm using `msysgit`. (Feel free to give a `linux/mac` only solution for others though)

EDIT:

I realize now that I could write a batch script to swap `c:\users\<me>\.gitconfig` but that seems more like a hack.

Comment: if it's any consolation, that hack is the first thing I thought of; I've always heard the .gitconfig goes in your home directory, but never "put your alter-ego's .gitconfig right here!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Git has global settings and per-repository settings.

Use:

```
$ git config --global user.name "qwertymk"
$ git config --global user.email "qwertymk@blah.com"
```

Then cd into the 'site' repository and use:

```
$ git config user.name "admin"
$ git config user.email "admin@mysite.com"
```